# minimal sufficient statistic of Cauchy distribution

Tags: statistical-inference, order-statistics

Given $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d with $f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Find the **minimal** sufficient statistic for $\frac{1}{\pi^{n}(\prod_{i=1}^{n} 1+(x_i-\theta)^2)}$.

**My question:** Using Bahadur's Factorization and Lehman-Scheffe's theorems, I obtain the sufficient statistic as $T(X) = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. However, the correct answer turned out to be $T(X) = (x_{(1)}, x_{(2)},\ldots, x_{(n)})$. But I cannot see why the first answer is incorrect, because if we are given the entire sample set, we could easily obtain the order statistic of that sample, so how could $T(X) = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is wrong?

Comment: Nobody wants to help me with this problem? I still could not see why the entire sample is NOT a minimal sufficient statistic;p Also, is minimal sufficient statistic UNIQUE?

Comment: Minimal sufficient statistic is definitely **not** unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T(X)=X is a sufficient statistics but NOT minimal.

T(X) = X contains more information than T(X) = (x(1),x(2),…,x(n)).

T(X) = X contains RANK while the order statistic does not. The order statistic only contains the values.

For example X = (1,2,3,4,5) and X= (1,3,2,4,5) both has the same order statistic T(X) = (1,2,3,4,5).

Comment: Would also like to add that an important property of a minimal sufficient statistic is that it can be expressed as a function of another non-minimal sufficient statistic. You can generate an ordered set from an unordered sample, but you cannot recover the original sample from an ordered sample. This complements the idea of a minimal statistic being the coarsest description of a random sample!

Answer (score 0):

The definition of minimal sufficient statistics from Casella's book is:

**Minimal Sufficient Statistic**

A sufficient statistic T(X) for $\theta$ is a minimal sufficient statistics if for any other sufficient statistics S(X), T(X) could be expressed as a function of S(X), such that S(X) should be an one-to-one transformation of T(X).

Judge by this, I think the minimal sufficient statistic should not be unique (If $T(X) = x$ is minimal statistic, then I suspect that $S_1(X) = log(x)$ or $S_2(X) = e^x$ are sufficient statistic. Conversely, then if we take $T(X) = e^x$ be the minimal sufficient statistic, then taking one-to-one transformation $S(X) = x$ is also a sufficient statistic. So how could we say that minimal sufficient statistic is unique??

Comment: I did not make that claim;p