# Find a minimal sufficient statistic for logistic distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample. Find a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

$$f(x|\theta)=\frac{e^{-(x-\theta)}}{(1+e^{-(x-\theta)})^2}$$,

$-\infty <x<\infty, -\infty <\theta<\infty$

The answer is the order statistics. I am not sure what the meaning of x and y have the same order statistics is.

Comment: The median is at $x= \theta$, so you might want to show the sample median is the estimator $\hat{\theta}$ you want.

Comment: @Aruralreader The answer is order statistics, not the median.

Comment: Please search the site. Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2975830/321264

Comment: The sample data $x=(6,-3,2,4)$ would give you the same information about $\theta$ as the sample data $y=(2,6,-3,4)$ since they have the same order statistics $(-3,2,4,6)$ and the actual order does not help