Order statistics are minimally sufficient for double-exponential
In the problem of finding a minimal sufficient statistic for the model: Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample whose common density is
$$
f_\theta(x) = \frac{exp\{- | x - \theta| \}}{2}, x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
I learned that $T(\{X_i\}_{i\leq n}) = (X_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)})$ is a minimally sufficient statistic, but how can I prove this? (Without an argument like it contains all the sample information).

Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2975830/321264

From Theoretical Statistics (Keener), example 3.13: The joint density is given by
$$
f_{\theta}(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \frac{1}{2^n}\exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - \theta| \right).
$$
Suppose the ratio $\frac{f_{\theta}(x_1, \dots, x_n)}{f_{\theta}(y_1, \dots, y_n)}$ is a constant function of $\theta$, then the difference between $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - \theta|$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i - \theta|$ must be a constant in $\theta$. Both of these functions are piecewise linear functions of $\theta$ with a slope that increases by two at each order statistic. The difference can only be constant in $\theta$ if $x$ and $y$ have the same order statistics. Thus the order statistics are minimal sufficient for this family of distributions.
If you're still not convinced, you can break down the difference $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - \theta| - \sum_{i=1}^n |y_i - \theta|$ into four summands based on the set of indices where the absolute values are positive/negative. By writing the cardinality of these sets as functions of $\theta$, you can simplify some stuff and isolate $\theta$ from the $x_i$ and $y_i$ to conclude that the order statistic is minimal sufficient.
