What's wrong with my counterexample: minimal sufficient statistic for Cauchy
It is well known that the order statistics are minimal sufficient for the Cauchy distribution. On the other hand we have the theorem that $T(X)$ is a minimal sufficient statistic if the ratio $f(X|\theta)/f(Y|\theta)$ is a constant function of $\theta$ if and only if $T(X) = T(Y)$.
For the Cauchy distribution this simplifies to
\begin{align*} 
\frac{f(X|\theta)}{f(Y|\theta)} = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1+(y_i-\theta)^2}{1+(x_i-\theta)^2}
\end{align*}
which is constant in $\theta$ if the order statistics are the same. But it is not immediate that it is also necessary that the order statistics are the same. This is what my counterexample is about.
Counterexample:
Let $y_i = x_i$ for all $i$. Then for some $i$ with $x_i>\theta$ change $y_i$ to $y_i = 2\theta-x_i$. This changes the order statistic $T(Y)$ but $(y_i-\theta)^2$ is unchanged and the ratio of densities must still be constant in $\theta$. The only if part is thus not satisfied and the order statistics are not minimal sufficient statistics.
So what is wrong?

Maybe this helps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2975830/minimal-sufficient-statistics-for-cauchy-distribution

Not really. It sketches a proof that the order statistics are minimal sufficient. According to the "ratio criterion" a statistic is minimal sufficient if the ratio is independent of $\theta$ if and only if the statistic is the same for the two samples. I give an example where the order statistics are different AND the ratio is independent of $\theta$. Hence they are not minimal sufficient. Or I am wrong.

Pick $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ such that
$$y_i=\begin{cases}
2\theta_0-x_1,&\text{if $i=1$,}\\
x_i,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Then the ratio $$r(\theta\mid x,y)=\frac{f(x\mid\theta)}{f(y\mid\theta)} = \frac{1+(2\theta_0-x_1-\theta)^2}{1+(x_1-\theta)^2}$$ is not a constant function of $\theta$. To see that, simply find two values $\theta_1,\theta_2\in\mathbb R$ such that $r(\theta_1)\ne r(\theta_2)$.
Your counterexample is

I exhibit two values $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $T(x)\ne T(y)$ but $r(\theta\mid x,y)$ is a constant function of $\theta$.

It is wrong because you fixed the variable $\theta$ when you picked your $x$ and $y$. But then you used the same letter $\theta$ for the parameter of the distribution (the variable that you have to vary to assess if the ratio depends on the parameter). In summary, your $x,y$ can't vary with the location parameter $\theta$. When building your counterexample, you can write $x,y$ as functions of other parameters that don't depend on $\theta$. Then your requirements
\begin{cases}
T(x)\ne T(y),\\
r(\theta\mid x,y) \text{ is a constant function of $\theta$},
\end{cases}
will be equations that those extra paramteres need to fulfil.
Clearly, there will be no solution to those equations, since we know that $T$ is minimal sufficient for $\theta$.

Thanks! That clarifies things.
